# replace comma with dot in scientific notation in r

Tags: r, csv

I want to read a csv-file that uses scientific notation and comma as a decimal separator into a data frame or vector. Then I want to use this data for further calculations. The problem is that R does not recognize the data as numeric. How can I translate this scientific notation with commas into the "correct" scientific notation with dots so I can use as numeric values?

I tried the following:

`mferg_1<-read.csv("file.csv",sep=";",dec=",",header=FALSE)`

When I look at the dataframe `mferg_1` the following appears (excerpt):

```
          V2        V3        V4        V5
14 3,063E+01 1,775E-02 6,641E-07 3,747E-02
```

I thought that I could replace the commas by using `gsub` or `sub`:

`mferg_1<-sub(",",".",mferg_1)`

But then `mferg_1` looks like this:

```
[1] "425" "388" "535" "472"
```

I fear there is an easy way to solve this problem but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: I employed dec=",". Nevertheless the data in the data frame appears with comma instead of dots. read.csv2 does not work any better.

Comment: When I read values exactly like yours using either `read.csv` or `read.csv2` (with the appropriate arguments set) it works fine. My best guess is that there is some other strange character in your file somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have something in your csv (a character line) that does not allow converting the columns to number, because the `dec = ","` parameter should work. See this example with your data:

```
text <- "3,063E+01 1,775E-02 6,641E-07 3,747E-02"
read.table(text=text, dec = ",")
     V1      V2        V3      V4
1 30.63 0.01775 6.641e-07 0.03747
```

Now, if you can't identify the problem (find what is preventing R to identify your columns as numeric), you could use `gsub`.

```
df <- read.table(text=text)
df <- sapply(df, gsub, pattern = ",", replacement= ".")
df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
     V1        V2        V3        V4 
3.063e+01 1.775e-02 6.641e-07 3.747e-02
```

Comment: That works, thank you!! Nevertheless I do not understand why gsub did not work for me as I employed it initially.

Comment: `gsub` will try to convert its input as character. If you pass the whole `data.frame` as an input, it can have 'unexpected' behaviour when the columns are `factors` (which is probably your case). But I can't know for sure what your problem was without the complete data. Best.

Comment: Future readers should beware that if you don't catch all "problem" characters that are causing columns to be read as characters, applying `as.numeric` without fixing those problems will generate `NA`s.